# Trying use Jinja in sls - No Luck

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I hope that You can help me to figured out what's wrong...

My sls file:

```
cat /srv/salt/test.sls
{% set serverproxy = ['194.110.220.91'] %}
/tmp/motd.xml:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://motd.jinja
    - template: jinja
```

My Jinja file:

cat /srv/salt/motd.jinja

```
Welcome to {{ grains['fqdn'] }}


    Server Stats at a Glance:
    ------------------------


    OS: {{ grains['osfullname'] }}
    Kernel: {{ grains['kernelrelease'] }}
    Memory: {{ grains['mem_total'] }} MB
    Proxy IP: {{ serverproxy }}
```

And error...

```
salt 'bbg-proxy' state.apply test
bbg-proxy:
----------
          ID: /tmp/motd.xml
    Function: file.managed
      Result: False
     Comment: Unable to manage file: Jinja variable 'serverproxy' is undefined
     Started: 10:47:04.060399
    Duration: 64.421 ms
     Changes:

Salt Version:
           Salt: 2018.3.3
```

If i don't use `{% set serverproxy = ['194.110.220.91'] %}` all working fine. 
What i'm missing?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the context in your file managed command

As an example here's what I have when playing with templates:

```
disable akonadi for {{ user }}:
  file.managed:
    - name: "/home/{{ user }}/.config/akonadi/akonadiserverrc"
    - source: salt://users/files/akonadiserverrc.jinja
    - template: jinja
    - user: {{ user }}
    - group: {{ user }}
    - replace: True
    - dir_mode: 755
    - mode: 644
    - makedirs: True
    - clean: True
    - context:
      user: {{ user }}
```

and in the akonadiserverrc.jinja I have this:

```
[%General]
Driver=QMYSQL

[QMYSQL]
Name=akonadi
Host=
Options="UNIX_SOCKET=/home/{{ user }}/.local/share/akonadi/socket-add3dev01/mysql.socket"
ServerPath=/usr/libexec/mysqld
StartServer=false

[Debug]
Tracer=null
```

The {{ user }} in the jinja file get correctly replace.

[Salt doc](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#jinja-in-files)